# JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization, javascriptserializer

**Summary**: How do I map a field name in JSON data to a field name of a .Net object when using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize ?

**Longer version**: I have the following JSON data coming to me from a server API (Not coded in .Net)

```
{"user_id":1234, "detail_level":"low"}
```

I have the following C# object for it:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataObject
{
    [XmlElement("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("detail_level")]
    public DetailLevel DetailLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Where DetailLevel is an enum with "Low" as one of the values.

This test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DataObjectSimpleParseTest()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    DataObject dataObject = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(JsonData);

    Assert.IsNotNull(dataObject);
    Assert.AreEqual(DetailLevel.Low, dataObject.DetailLevel);
    Assert.AreEqual(1234, dataObject.UserId);
}
```

And the last two asserts fail, since there is no data in those fields. If I change the JSON data to

```
 {"userid":1234, "detaillevel":"low"}
```

Then it passes. But I can't change the server's behaviour, and I want the client classes to have well-named properties in the C# idiom. I can't use LINQ to JSON since I want it to work outside of Silverlight. It looks like the XmlElement tags are having no effect. I don't know where I got the idea they were relevant at all, they probably aren't.

How do you do field name mapping in JavaScriptSerializer? Can it be done at all?

Comment: I hate `JavaScriptSerializer`. `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` uses it through the static `JsonExtensions.Serializer` property, which means changing it during runtime could affect other code that expects it to be unchanged. Many of these classes are that way, unfortunately. :(

Comment: [XmlElement("user_id")] XmlElement does not exist, where did you get that ? post fiull namespace or import dll's

Comment: use [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement ("user_id")]  <-- fullnamespace

Answer (score 74):

I took another try at it, using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class. This solves it:

The code looks like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class DataObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "detail_level")]
    public string DetailLevel { get; set; }
}
```

And the test is:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

[TestMethod]
public void DataObjectSimpleParseTest()
{
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DataObject));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(JsonData));
        DataObject dataObject = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as DataObject;

        Assert.IsNotNull(dataObject);
        Assert.AreEqual("low", dataObject.DetailLevel);
        Assert.AreEqual(1234, dataObject.UserId);
}
```

The only drawback is that I had to change DetailLevel from an enum to a string - if you keep the enum type in place, the DataContractJsonSerializer expects to read a numeric value and fails. See [DataContractJsonSerializer and Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794838/datacontractjsonserializer-and-enums) for further details.

In my opinion this is quite poor, especially as JavaScriptSerializer handles it correctly. This is the exception that you get trying to parse a string into an enum:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type DataObject. The value 'low' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'. --->
System.Xml.XmlException: The value 'low' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'. --->  
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format
```

And marking up the enum like this does not change this behaviour:

```
[DataContract]
public enum DetailLevel
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "low")]
    Low,
   ...
 }
```

This also seems to work in Silverlight.

Comment: Great solution!

With .Net 4.5 seems working fine for enum members with just plain [DataMember] declaration (no need for [EnumMember] etc.)

Comment: What's in your JsonData? When I do this as you've written, I get a SerializationException to the effect that the Serializer is expecting a root element, as though it's expecting XML.

My JSON data is {"user": "THEDOMAIN\\MDS", "password": "JJJJ"}

Answer (score 20):

By creating a custom [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) you can map any name to any property. But it does require hand coding the map, which is less than ideal.

```
public class DataObjectJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    private static readonly Type[] _supportedTypes = new[]
    {
        typeof( DataObject )
    };

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes 
    { 
        get { return _supportedTypes; } 
    }

    public override object Deserialize( IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, 
                                        Type type, 
                                        JavaScriptSerializer serializer )
    {
        if( type == typeof( DataObject ) )
        {
            var obj = new DataObject();
            if( dictionary.ContainsKey( "user_id" ) )
                obj.UserId = serializer.ConvertToType<int>( 
                                           dictionary["user_id"] );
            if( dictionary.ContainsKey( "detail_level" ) )
                obj.DetailLevel = serializer.ConvertToType<DetailLevel>(
                                           dictionary["detail_level"] );

            return obj;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize( 
            object obj, 
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer )
    {
        var dataObj = obj as DataObject;
        if( dataObj != null )
        {
            return new Dictionary<string,object>
            {
                {"user_id", dataObj.UserId },
                {"detail_level", dataObj.DetailLevel }
            }
        }
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like so:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serialzer.RegisterConverters( new[]{ new DataObjectJavaScriptConverter() } );
var dataObj = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>( json );
```

Answer (score 13):

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) will do what you want (disclaimer: I'm the author of the package). It supports reading DataContract/DataMember attributes as well as its own to change the property names. Also there is the StringEnumConverter class for serializing enum values as the name rather than the number.

Comment: A two-line code examples showing using the attribute would be nice to see in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

There is no standard support for renaming properties in `JavaScriptSerializer` however you can quite easily add your own:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;

public class JsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

            if (jsonProperty != null && dictionary.ContainsKey(jsonProperty.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[jsonProperty.Name]);
            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey(member.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[member.Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Key, member.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (!kvp.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, object>)))
                {
                    SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }


    private void SetMemberValue(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, MemberInfo member, object obj, object value)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;                
            property.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, property.PropertyType), null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            field.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, field.FieldType));
        }
    }


    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

            if (jsonProperty != null)
            {
                values[jsonProperty.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
            else
            {
                values[member.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    private object GetMemberValue(MemberInfo member, object obj)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
            return property.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            return field.GetValue(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }


    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get 
        {
            return new[] { typeof(DataObject) };
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public JsonPropertyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The `DataObject` class then becomes:

```
public class DataObject
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("detail_level")]
    public DetailLevel DetailLevel { get; set; }
}
```

I appreicate this might be a little late but thought other people wanting to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` rather than the `DataContractJsonSerializer` might appreciate it.

Comment: I've used your code with generics like JsonConverter<T> : JavaScriptConverter so this class can be used with any type.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class inherited from JavaScriptConverter.  You must then implement three things:

**Methods-**

1. Serialize
2. Deserialize

**Property-**

1. SupportedTypes

You can use  the JavaScriptConverter class when you need more control over the serialization and deserialization process.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new MyCustomConverter() });

DataObject dataObject = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(JsonData);
```

[Here is a link for further information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I have used the using Newtonsoft.Json as below. Create an object:

```
 public class WorklistSortColumn
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dir")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
  }
```

Now Call the below method to serialize to Json object as shown below.

```
string sortColumn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(worklistSortColumn);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want to go for [Newtonsoft Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or `DataContractJsonSerializer` for some reason (I can't think of any :) ), here is an implementation of `JavaScriptConverter` that supports `DataContract` and `enum` to `string` conversion -

```
    public class DataContractJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {
        private static readonly List<Type> _supportedTypes = new List<Type>();

        static DataContractJavaScriptConverter()
        {
            foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes)
            {
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(DataContractAttribute)))
                {
                    _supportedTypes.Add(type);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool ConvertEnumToString = false;

        public DataContractJavaScriptConverter() : this(false)
        {
        }

        public DataContractJavaScriptConverter(bool convertEnumToString)
        {
            ConvertEnumToString = convertEnumToString;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
        {
            get { return _supportedTypes; }
        }

        public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(DataContractAttribute)))
            {
                try
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                    IEnumerable<MemberInfo> members = ((IEnumerable<MemberInfo>)type.GetFields())
                        .Concat(type.GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanWrite && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0))
                        .Where((member) => Attribute.IsDefined(member, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)));
                    foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
                    {
                        DataMemberAttribute attribute = (DataMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(DataMemberAttribute));
                        object value;
                        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(attribute.Name, out value) == false)
                        {
                            if (attribute.IsRequired)
                            {
                                throw new SerializationException(String.Format("Required DataMember with name {0} not found", attribute.Name));
                            }
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                        {
                            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
                            object fieldValue;
                            if (ConvertEnumToString && field.FieldType.IsEnum)
                            {
                                fieldValue = Enum.Parse(field.FieldType, value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fieldValue = serializer.ConvertToType(value, field.FieldType);
                            }
                            field.SetValue(instance, fieldValue);
                        }
                        else if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                        {
                            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
                            object propertyValue;
                            if (ConvertEnumToString && property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                            {
                                propertyValue = Enum.Parse(property.PropertyType, value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                propertyValue = serializer.ConvertToType(value, property.PropertyType);
                            }
                            property.SetValue(instance, propertyValue);
                        }
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (obj != null && Attribute.IsDefined(obj.GetType(), typeof(DataContractAttribute)))
            {
                Type type = obj.GetType();
                IEnumerable<MemberInfo> members = ((IEnumerable<MemberInfo>)type.GetFields())
                    .Concat(type.GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanRead && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0))
                    .Where((member) => Attribute.IsDefined(member, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)));
                foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
                {
                    DataMemberAttribute attribute = (DataMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(DataMemberAttribute));
                    object value;
                    if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                    {
                        FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
                        if (ConvertEnumToString && field.FieldType.IsEnum)
                        {
                            value = field.GetValue(obj).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            value = field.GetValue(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
                        if (ConvertEnumToString && property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                        {
                            value = property.GetValue(obj).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            value = property.GetValue(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(attribute.Name))
                    {
                        throw new SerializationException(String.Format("More than one DataMember found with name {0}", attribute.Name));
                    }
                    dictionary[attribute.Name] = value;
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```

Note: This `DataContractJavaScriptConverter` will only handle `DataContract` classes defined in the assembly where it is placed. If you want classes from separate assemblies, modify the `_supportedTypes` list accordingly in the static constructror.

This can be used as follows -

```
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DataContractJavaScriptConverter(true) });
    DataObject dataObject = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(JsonData);
```

The `DataObject` class would look like this -

```
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class DataObject
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "detail_level")]
        public string DetailLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

Please note that this solution doesn't handle `EmitDefaultValue` and `Order` properties supported by `DataMember` attribute.

Comment: ASP.NET uses `JavascriptSerializer` when converting client json (via ajax to a WebMethod) to a .NET object, so users like me working on a website who want to handle client data have no choice but to use Microsoft's version. For serialization, we can of course use Newtonsoft, but deserialization requires this.
Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/ObjectConverter.cs,809b4f13600ad28c,references

Answer (score 0):

My requirements included:

- must honor the dataContracts
- must deserialize dates in the format received in service
- must handle colelctions
- must target 3.5
- must NOT add an external dependency, especially not Newtonsoft (I'm creating a distributable package myself)
- must not be deserialized by hand

My solution in the end was to use SimpleJson(https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json).

Although you can install it via a nuget package, I included just that single SimpleJson.cs file (with the MIT license) in my project and referenced it.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generizied version of Tom Maher's answer.  This will automatically register all nested property types in your `DataObject` to the converter so they can make use of the `JsonPropertyAttribute`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;

public class JavascriptConverterFactory<T> : JavaScriptConverter where T : class
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));
            if (jsonProperty != null && dictionary.ContainsKey(jsonProperty.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[jsonProperty.Name]);
            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey(member.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[member.Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Key, member.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (!kvp.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, object>)))
                {
                    SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    private void SetMemberValue(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, MemberInfo member, object obj, object value)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
            property.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, property.PropertyType), null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            field.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, field.FieldType));
        }
    }


    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

            if (jsonProperty != null)
            {
                values[jsonProperty.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
            else
            {
                values[member.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    private object GetMemberValue(MemberInfo member, object obj)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
            return property.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            return field.GetValue(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { typeof(T) }.Concat(GetAllNestedTypes(typeof(T)));
        }
    }

    public static JavaScriptSerializer Create()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new JavascriptConverterFactory<T>() });

        return serializer;
    }

    private static Type[] GetAllNestedTypes(Type type)
    {
        ArrayList types = new ArrayList();
        AddNestedMemberPropertyTypesRecursively(types, type);
        return (Type[])types.ToArray(typeof(Type));
    }

    private static ArrayList AddNestedMemberPropertyTypesRecursively(ArrayList types, Type type)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            if (member is PropertyInfo)
            {
                PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
                bool isAlreadyInArray = types.Contains(property.PropertyType);

                if (!isAlreadyInArray)
                {
                    types.Add(property.PropertyType);
                    if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
                    {
                        Type arrayElementType = property.PropertyType.GetElementType();
                        isAlreadyInArray = types.Contains(arrayElementType);
                        if (!isAlreadyInArray)
                        {
                            types.Add(arrayElementType);
                            AddNestedMemberPropertyTypesRecursively(types, arrayElementType);
                        }
                    }
                    AddNestedMemberPropertyTypesRecursively(types, property.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }

        return types;
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public JsonPropertyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DataObject
{
    [JsonProperty("nested:dataobject")]
    NestedDataObject nestedObject { get; set; }
}

public class NestedDataObject
{
    [JsonProperty("some-other-string")]
    string someOtherString { get; set; }
}
```

How to use:

```cs
public DataObject GetData(responseContent)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = JavascriptConverterFactory<DataObject>.Create();
    DataObject deserializedData = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(responseContent);
    return deserializedData;
}
```