# JsonResult equivalent to [DataMember(Name="Test")]

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-2, jsonresult

I have a method doing this:

```
public JsonResult Layar(string countryCode, string timestamp, string userId, 
                        string developerId, string layarName, double radius, 
                        double lat, double lon, double accuracy)
{
    LayarModel model = new LayarModel(lat, lon, radius);

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It returns this object:

```
public class LayarModel
{        
    private List<HotSpot> _hotSpots = new List<HotSpot>();
    public List<HotSpot> HotSpots { get { return _hotSpots; } set { _hotSpots = value; } }    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorString { get; set; }
}
```

I want the JSON to be

```
{"hotspots": [{
    "distance": 100, 
    "attribution": "The Location of the Layar Office", 
    "title": "The Layar Office",  
    "lon": 4884339, 
    "imageURL": http:\/\/custom.layar.nl\/layarimage.jpeg,
    "line4": "1019DW Amsterdam",
    "line3": "distance:%distance%",
    "line2": "Rietlandpark 301",
    "actions": [],
    "lat": 52374544,
    "type": 0,
    "id": "test_1"}], 
 "layer": "snowy4",
 "errorString": "ok", 
 "morePages": false,
 "errorCode": 0,
 "nextPageKey": null
}
```

Everything comes out capitalised as in the class being returned (`HotSpots` instead of `hotspots`).

I have tried DataContract and DataMembers(Name="Test") but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

JsonResult() uses JavaScriptSerializer internally for serialization, and it seems it doesn't support defining the serialized property names using attributes.

DataContractJsonSerializer supports this, so that may be a way to go.

Some links that may be useful:

- JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names : [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)
- DataContractJsonSerializer Versus JavaScriptSerializer : Changing Field Names: http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2010/06/datacontractjsonserializer-versus.html

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend installing json.NET but the rest is a lot easier. Below is an extension method I am using in my current application to provide better reuse, feel free to adapt it to your needs, but it should do what you need right out of the box.

```
public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
{
    public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                //http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx
                #if DEBUG
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented, //Makes the outputted Json easier reading by a human, only needed in debug
                #endif
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() //Makes the default for properties outputted by Json to use camelCaps
            };
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
                                    ? ContentType
                                    : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data != null)
        {
            JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) {Formatting = Formatting};

            JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);

            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonNetExtenionMethods
{
    public static ActionResult JsonNet(this Controller controller, object data)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult() {Data = data};
    }

    public static ActionResult JsonNet(this Controller controller, object data, string contentType)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult() { Data = data, ContentType = contentType };
    }

    public static ActionResult JsonNet(this Controller controller, object data, Formatting formatting)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult() {Data = data, Formatting = formatting};
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using it.

```
public JsonNetResult Layar(string countryCode, string timestamp, string userId, 
                        string developerId, string layarName, double radius, 
                        double lat, double lon, double accuracy)
{
    LayarModel model = new LayarModel(lat, lon, radius);

    return this.JsonNet(model);
}
```

The part to note that solves your problem specifically is when the `ContractResolver` on the `JsonSerializerSettings` is set to use `new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`

This way you never have to set custom naming again.