# Create JSon array from code behind file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

How can I created arraylist as shown below using asp.net, c#.  I can created such array using [JsonTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) , but don't want to add any other dll as part of my solution.

```
  [{ "id": "slide-img-1", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "nature beauty photography" },
  { "id": "slide-img-2", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" },
  { "id": "slide-img-3", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" },
  { "id": "slide-img-4", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" },
  { "id": "slide-img-5", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" },
  { "id": "slide-img-6", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here" },
  { "id": "slide-img-7", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "add your description here"}];
```

Thanks,

Ashish

Answer (score 4):

You can use [a JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

Assuming the entity in your array is something like:

```
public class Entity 
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string client { get; set; }
  public string desc {get; set; }

  [ScriptIgnore]
  public string PropertyThatIsIgnored { get;set; }
}
```

Then it is useable like so:

```
Entity[] entities = ...;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(entities);
```

Alternatively, if more complex serialization is required, you may consider using [a DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), since it allows [more extensibility when serializing / deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names).

Comment: I have List<CustomClass> where I have multiple variables. I want to have id,client and desc only.

Comment: @ashish.chotalia I have updated my answer to show how a property can be ignored, however if you wish to change property names I'd advise using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: Yups, that works. Can you please left me know how can I auto generate id ?

Comment: @ashish.chotalia please ask a separate SO question for that, a lot more information will be required - at what point you wish to generate the id, how it will be mapped back to your entity etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JavaScriptSerializer` class that comes with .NET framework.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string myJson = js.Serialize(new string[] {"A", "B", "C"});
```