# Changing property names for serializing

Tags: c#, json, serialization

My class has a property 'PropertyA', I want this to appear as 'PropertyB' in a JSON object when it's serialized. Is there any sort of attribute I can use?

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using? JavaScriptSerializer? JSON.NET? DataContractJsonSerializer? ...?

Comment: What JSON serialization library are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should've gave more details - DataContractJsonSerializer is what I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For `Json.NET` and `DataContractJsonSerializer` use [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574795):

```
[DataMember(Name="PropertyB")]
T PropertyA { ... }
```

Make sure that your class is decorated with the `[DataContract]` attribute as well.

If you're using JavaScriptSerializer, you need to create derived implementation, as described here:
[JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Comment: and if I do not have access to change the DataMenber property? can I add a translator or something like that at serializing time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091862/change-the-way-json-net-serializes-property-names

Comment: Also don't forget to add `[DataContract]` on top of the class

Comment: [DataContract] was what I needed as well.  Thanks @HosseinNarimaniRad !

Comment: ATTENTION! Adding `[DataContract]` does change the serialization logic. Without it all properties will be serialized, after decorating the class with it only properties decorated with `DataMemberAttribute` will be serialized/deserialized.