# deserialize custom object returned from web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Client make get request to web api method and get an object as response the problem is I cant desirialize this object..

client method, making get request to web api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57752");
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Auth/Login/" + user.Username + "/" + user.Password).Result;
                JsonResult result = null;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonResult>().Result;
                    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    User validUser = json_serializer.Deserialize<User>(result.Data.ToString());//Throws Exp.
                }
```

I want to simply put this object instance returned from api to validUser..

error message:

> Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'

here are models:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
    {
        //public string _id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public void EncryptPassword()
        {
            Password = Encrypter.Encode(this.Password);
        }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling the deserializer what to deserialize to.  This

```
User validUser = (User)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(result.Data.ToString());
```

deserializes into an object and then attempts to cast that object as a `User`, which is going to fail.  You need to use the generic method:

```
User validUser = json_serializer.Deserialize<User>(result.Data.ToString());
```

It's entirely possible you will need to do more work if the JSON names and the class names/struictures are different [Changing property names for serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456075/changing-property-names-for-serializing).

Comment: Yeah but this time I face with this edited post. any advice?