# Creating a JSON string, if the left-hand varaible has dashes in

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a json string to send via a httprequest, I have json string like so:

```
{
    "a-string": "123",
    "another-string": "hello",
    "another": "1"
}
```

My problem is, if I try and generate it like so

```
 string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
    "a-string" = "123",
    "another-string" = "hello",
    "another" = "1"
    });
```

Leads to:[image]

So what is a way of trying to do the above, without getting that error?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456075/changing-property-names-for-serializing)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456075/changing-property-names-for-serializing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Json NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) NuGet package. Then use my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response) to create a C# class for you json. Since your json has names in them which are not allowed as property names in C#, you can use the `JsonPropety` attribute so it can use it during serialization. Here is all of the code:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("a-string")]
    public string astring { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("another-string")]
    public string anotherstring { get; set; }
    public string another { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var root = new Rootobject { another = "1", anotherstring = "hello", astring = "123" };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```