# Is it possible to have a field named bool in C#?

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch

I am sitting playing with elastic search from C#, and I wanted to create a query using an anonymous type in C# serialized to JSON. But I ran in to a problem as I need JSON that looks like this in one part:

```
{"bool": {<unimportant for question>}}
```

This would translate into a c# class that has a field named bool. Is this possible? (My guess is no...)

I think I will need custom serialization, or maybe elastic search provides some other alternative name for bool.

Comment: `bool` is a valid field name in .NET. However in order to _access_ it from C# code you need to use `@`, as @flem's answer suggests.

Comment: I added the misisng quotation marks now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to name variables the same as keywords you can prefix them with `@`.

bool @bool = false;

I would avoid doing this in ALL circumstances where possible. It's just plain confusing.

Comment: Yes I am just trying it out some new technologies nothing serious. Thanks the "@" worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can set the name in a `[DataMember]` attribute, but you need to use real classes (not anonymous).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

// You must apply a DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute 
// to a class to have it serialized by the DataContractSerializer.
[DataContract()]
class Enterprise : IExtensibleDataObject
{

    [DataMember(Name = "bool")]
    public bool CaptainKirk {get; set;}

    // more stuff here
}
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DateMember` attribute to specify what the serialised name is:

```
[DataMember(Name = "bool")]
public string MyBoolean { get; set; }
```

See also: [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I would normally do but I was trying it out with an anonymous type...