# Giving a property two identifiers for deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm deserializing JSON into an object with JavaScriptSerializer in C#.

The object has the following properties:

```
public string plugin_name { get; set; }
public string slug { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }
public string logo_full { get; set; }
public string[] categories { get; set; }
public Version[] versions { get; set; }
```

The thing is that the names (e.g. `plugin_name`) don't follow the usual naming guidelines (pascal case). Is there any simple way that I can give a property two identifiers? Or is there anything else that could help me achieve what I want. I'm aware that I could do this:

```
public string PluginName { get; set; }
public string plugin_name { set { PluginName = value; } }
```

But is there any simpler and cleaner solution to this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are no conventions with this. It maps 1-to-1...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm), you can add an attribute to assist in this mapping instead of having to create this redirect:

```
[JsonProperty("plugin_name")]
public string PluginName{get;set;}
```

But, as pointed out, this is specific to Json.NET. Is it possible for you to use that instead?

Comment: That attribute is for Json.net. That'd be a good alternative to recommend, but does not directly address his issue with the `JavaScriptSerializer`. http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm lists the differences well, including this one ("Attribute property name customization").

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried this out and it works perfectly!