# C# Object to JSON convert

Tags: c#, json

I would like to get next structure in JSON:

```
{
    'for-sale': { name: 'For Sale', type: 'folder' },
    'vehicles': { name: 'Vehicles', type: 'folder' },
    'rentals': { name: 'Rentals', type: 'folder' },
}
```

I can use `JavaScriptSerializer` to convert .net class to JSON format. But witch structure my class must have for above sample data?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but take a look at [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("for-sale")]
    public IList<Item> forSale { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> vehicles { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> rentals { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

You could also use the DataContractJsonSerializer and instead you would use the following classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "for-sale")]
    public IList<Item> forSale { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Item> vehicles { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Item> rentals { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You would have to have forSale or something as for-sale is not a valid name for a property.

Comment: This approach may cause problems if you want to add extra items.

Comment: I'd suggest the use of the JSON serializer in `ServiceStack.Text`, no need for all those ugly attribute adornments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a

```
var theStructure = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>()
```

and add data to it like:

```
theStructure.Add("for-sale", new Dictionary<string, string>() {("For Sale", "folder")});
```

Comment: I wouldn't go with this approach when there are easy ways to map JSON on to POCOs.