# Reading JSON String to VB .NET Object

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I did this to convert JSON formatted string to VB.NET Object.

I cannot find why it does not work!

jsonSettingsWrapper.vb

```
Public Class jsonSettingsWrapper
    'Public setting As jsonSettings
    Public Property setting As jsonSettings
        Get
            Return m_setting
        End Get
        Set(value As jsonSettings)
            m_setting = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_setting As jsonSettings
End Class

Public Class jsonSettings
    Public Property root_folder_path As String
        Get
            Return m_root_folder_path
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_root_folder_path = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_root_folder_path As String

    Public Property ignored_files As String()
        Get
            Return m_ignored_files
        End Get
        Set(value As String())
            m_ignored_files = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ignored_files As String()

    Public Property last_pack_date As String
        Get
            Return m_last_pack_date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_last_pack_date = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_last_pack_date As String

    Public Property last_push_date As String
        Get
            Return m_last_push_date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_last_push_date = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_last_push_date As String

    Public Property no_of_packs As Integer
        Get
            Return m_no_of_packs
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_no_of_packs = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_no_of_packs As Integer

    Public Property packs_array As packs()
        Get
            Return m_packs_array
        End Get
        Set(value As packs())
            m_packs_array = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_packs_array As packs()
End Class

Public Class packs
    Public Property filename As String
        Get
            Return m_filename
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_filename = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_filename As String

    Public Property pack_date As String
        Get
            Return m_pack_date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_pack_date = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_pack_date As String
End Class
```

Form1.Vb

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports WindowsApplication1.jsonSettingsWrapper

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim settingsString As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("settings.json")
        MsgBox(settingsString)
        Dim settings = ser.Deserialize(Of jsonSettingsWrapper)(settingsString)
        MsgBox(settings.setting) 'empty
        MsgBox(settings.setting.root_folder_path) 
        ' ^ ^ Error: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FilesSync.exe
    End Sub
```

As mentioned in the code comments, error occur when it try to access some of its value. Can anyone put some light on why is this happening. Where am i doing it wrong?

EDIT: The JSON I used is:

```
{"settings": {
    "root_folder_path": "ab",
    "ignored_files": [
        "cd",
        "ef"
    ],
    "last_pack_date": "12",
    "last_push_date": "21",
    "no_of_packs": 3,
    "packs_array": [
        {
            "filename": "aa",
            "pack_date": "21"
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: I Would recommend using a library to do JSON parsing, e.g. JSON.NET, if you don't have a specific need to do this yourself.

Comment: You should show an example of the JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON use the property name "settings" but your class use "setting", change your class to use the right name

```
Public Class jsonSettingsWrapper
    'Public setting As jsonSettings
    Public Property settings() As jsonSettings
        Get
            Return m_setting
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As jsonSettings)
            m_setting = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_setting As jsonSettings
End Class
```

or use [DataContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)