# Class Properties display name when serialize class

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string v1 { set; get; }
    public string v2 { set; get; }
    public string v3 { set; get; }
    public string i1 { set; get; }
    public string i2 { set; get; }
    public string i3 { set; get; }
    public string error { set; get; }
    public string date { set; get; }
}
```

when i Serialize the class

```
 MyClass meter = new MyClass();
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(meter);
```

i get

```
{
    "v1":"2342",
    "v2":"2336",
    "v3":"2332",
    "i1":"38.90",
    "i2":"42.21",
    "i3":"30.87",
    "error":"",
    "date":"26/02/2015 08:16:14"
}
```

how can i change the display name of every member (like [ScriptIgnore])

i tried [Display(Name = "myname")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways

1) Use the `Newtonsoft.Json` and just add the property name to display There are this way

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
 public string Owner { get; set; }
```

2) If you stick with `javascriptserializer` then here is the code to how to do it. 
 [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

I think you should use the [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) why reinvent the wheel??

Comment: is there a function for it to force it to use the class object's property name instead of the JSON object's properties?