# JSON string not Deserialize properly with boolean and string

Tags: .net, json, c#-4.0, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON response.

The result string is

```
{"Success":false,"Response":"Error"}
```

And I've built the class

```
class JsonResponse
{
  public bool cSuccess { get; set; }
  public string cResponse { get; set; }
}
```

And parse with the code

```
JsonResponse message = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonResponse>(result);
```

However only `message.cSuccess` is populated with false, while `message.cResponse` is still null.

Is there any mistake I've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the properties in your class need to match the properties in the JSON string.

Change the class to be:

```
class JsonResponse
{
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note that you *can* have different names in your class, but without using a library like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), it's quite complex. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names