# Deserializing list of items

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have following sample Json string:

```
{"Items":[{"Id":"20","CaptureCategoryTypeId":5021,"Name":"24270","Description":"FSH  CARRIBEAN CAPTAIN","IsEnabled":true}],"TotalResults":0}
```

I need to deserialize the same but I don't want to keep my  class name as following:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int CaptureCategoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
}
```

I want to keep custom class name such DataDetails. How that can be achieved in c#?

Comment: What do you mean you want to keep custom class name? Do you want to rename RootObject to DataDetails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Comment: Yeah rootobject to something else and Item as Data details.

Comment: @Chanchal I added an answer it works fine.

Comment: @Tech1337: Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what your question is but you can just change the class names to whatever you want. Below is a working example.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string JSONInput = @"{""Items"":[{""Id"":""20"",""CaptureCategoryTypeId"":5021,""Name"":""24270"",""Description"":""FSH CARRIBEAN CAPTAIN"",""IsEnabled"":true}],""TotalResults"":0}";
            BlahObject deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlahObject>(JSONInput);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class DataDetails
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int CaptureCategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlahObject
    {
        public List<DataDetails> Items { get; set; }
        public int TotalResults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I exactly wanted this !