# How to assign enum values to class object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enumeration

i have used following enum

```
public enum Vehicle
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Use of Carriage")]
    UseofCarriage
}
```

i want to use that in class object but with following code i am getting that enum value in json as 0
instead i want the value of enummember

```
public void TestCase1()
    {
        // Arrange
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.Vehicle = Vehicle.UseofCarriage;
   
        // Act
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vehicle);

        // Assert
        _test.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

can anybody suggest

Comment: Enums are basically fancy integers so getting 0 in your output here is fully expected.

Comment: Possible this answer is what you need: [Serialize enum to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159750/8017690)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))`] in the class Vehicle. It should produce the result you expect in the test output.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty("Vehicle")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Some documentation about serialisation attributes here in Json.net :
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm