# Passing enum value as string

Tags: wcf

This is an example code:

```
[DataContract]
public enum SessionOperation
{
    [EnumMember]
    Update,
    [EnumMember]
    Register
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long SessionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public SessionOperation Operation { get; set; }
}
```

And operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
BaseResponseObject Request(SessionData requestObject);
```

What I am trying to achieve in my RESTful WCF service is to pass SessionOperation as string and not as value?
Like:

```
{"ClientId": 11935,"SessionId": 635193261351796051, "Operation": "Register"}
```

Is it somehow possible without manual altering?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like so:

```
EnumMember(Value="Update")
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Didn't worked. I get: There was an error deserializing the object of type RequestObject. The value 'Register' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. WCF service can't parse JSON enum field with string value within. Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121010/wcf-deserialize-enum-as-string