# How to Customize Deserialization of a JSON enum in .NET?

Tags: c#, wcf, json, xsd, datacontractserializer

I have the following sample C# code that is auto-genereated from an xsd using the svcutils.exe application.

```
    [DataContract]
    public enum Foo
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "bar")]
        Bar = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value = "baz")]
        Baz = 2
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class UNameIt
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public long Id { get; private set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "foo")]
        public Foo Foo { get; private set; }
    }
```

The following is a unit test that attempts to deserialise a sample JSON document to the UNameIt class.

```
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonSerializer_Fixture
    {
        public const string JsonData = @"{ ""id"":123456,
                                           ""name"":""John Doe"",
                                           ""foo"":""Bar""}";

        [TestMethod]
        public void DataObjectSimpleParseTest()
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UNameIt));

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(JsonData));
            UNameIt dataObject = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as UNameIt;

            Assert.IsNotNull(dataObject);
            Assert.AreEqual(123456, dataObject.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(Foo.Baz, dataObject.Foo);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the test fails giving the following reason:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an
>   error deserializing the object of type MyNamespace.Units.UNameIt. The
>   value 'Bar' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'.

The test will pass if I update my JSON string to replace the string specifier for the Enum to an integer e.g.

```
public const string JsonData = @"{ ""id"":123456,
                                   ""name"":""John Doe"",
                                    ""foo"":""1""}";
```

I do not have the flexibility to the change the supplied JSON so I have to figure out how to convert the string Enum representation perhaps on serialisation. Ideally, I would like to facilitate this without having to change my autogenerate class because once I re-generate the class I would loose my changes.

I am wondering if it would be possible to extend the DataContractJsonSerializer to custom handle Enumerations? Or perhaps there is better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the 'private' modifier on the set method of class UNameIt? And try your test  writing "bar" lowercase...

Comment: it's  recommended to avoid expose enums in wcf data contracts because they create subtle backwards compatible problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/788281/52277

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataContractJsonSerializer and Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794838/datacontractjsonserializer-and-enums)

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is **by design**. Here's a quote from the [Enumerations and JSON paragraph on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx):

> Enumeration member values are treated as numbers in JSON, which is
>   different from how they are treated in data contracts, where they are
>   included as member names.

Moreover the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) will automatically serialize all enumerations, so the [EnumMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.aspx) is actually ignored.

For a **workaround**, take a look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794962/26396).

Answer (score 0):

This is work :

```
var ret = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<tblGridProjects>(retApi.Item2);
```

But you can't use datamembers attributes, so can't rename properties.
You must set the name of the property like Json sended.