# Json.NET StringEnumConverter not always working

Tags: c#, enums, json.net

I have an enum:

```
public enum FilterOperator
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "eq")]
        Equals,
        [EnumMember(Value = "gt")]
        GreaterThan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "lt")]
        LessThan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "in")]
        In,
        [EnumMember(Value = "like")]
        Like
    }
```

and a class that includes an enum property:

```
public class GridFilter
{
    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

The object is passed in via a WebAPI action and deserializes as expected for "like" and "in" but it doesn't for "lg" or "gt". Any idea why?

**UPDATE: Well the reason "like" and "in" work is that they match the enum name. Renaming GreaterThan to Gt (etc) works. So the real issue is why isn't StringEnumConverter being used?**

Comment: Have you tried decorating `FilterOperator` itself with `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`?

Comment: Hmm, didn't realize one could set it up like that. Sadly it didn't fix the problem but didn't make it worse either

Comment: Given that 'like' and 'in' are spelled the same as their decorator, I suspect that your decorator isn't actually doing anything for them either.

Comment: You are correct, I removed [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] and it still worked the same. So am I misusing StringEnumConverter and EnumMember?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999731/how-to-customize-deserialization-of-a-json-enum-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help! I realized what I've done. Sadly it's pretty dumb, I apologize in advanced for the run around.

Since I am using GET I am sending the parameters as url query parameters so WebAPI is using the normal ModelBinder to map names and not JSON.NET. I'm not actually sending JSON so this make total sense. This question helped me realize this:
[Complex type is getting null in a ApiController parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter)

My choices are create a custom model binder that handles the enum correctly or change to a POST and send the data with JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 11):

Well, you must place the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute directly on the `enum` declaration instead of the `Operator` property of `GridFilter` if you want it to be used when deserializing outside the context of the class `GridFilter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] // Add this
public enum FilterOperator
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "eq")]
    Equals,
    [EnumMember(Value = "gt")]
    GreaterThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "lt")]
    LessThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "in")]
    In,
    [EnumMember(Value = "like")]
    Like
}

public class GridFilter
{
    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter")] // Remove this
    public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, and I haven't tested it.

I looked at the documentation for [`EnumMemberAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), and it says:

> To use `EnumMemberAttribute`, create an enumeration and apply the `DataContractAttribute` attribute to the enumeration. Then apply the `EnumMemberAttribute` attribute to each member that needs to be in the serialization stream.

That's for the `DataContractSerializer`, of course, but I'm thinking perhaps JSON.net takes that same rule into account?

I'd try applying `[DataContract]` to the `enum`.

```
[DataContract]
public enum FilterOperator
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "eq")]
    Equals,
    [EnumMember(Value = "gt")]
    GreaterThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "lt")]
    LessThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "in")]
    In,
    [EnumMember(Value = "like")]
    Like
}
```

It seems arbitrary, and redundant. And I know JSON.net doesn't *typically* depend on that sort of thing, but maybe in this case it does?

I'm also noticing that it appears the `DataContractSerializer` ignores elements without `[EnumMember]` if `[DataContract]` is present, so it might have to be this way for backwards compatibility. Again, not super logical. But that's all I've got.

---

**Edit:** In true developer fashion, rather than just *testing* this, I went into the source code. The part that reads the `EnumMemberAttribute` can be found [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/EnumUtils.cs) on line 55, and it does this:

```
n2 = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true) 
      .Cast<EnumMemberAttribute>() 
      .Select(a => a.Value) 
      .SingleOrDefault() ?? f.Name;
```

That makes me think that what you've got should be working.

---

**Edit 2:**

Alright, so this is odd. I just tried it myself and found it working.

```
public enum FilterOperator
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "eq")]
    Equals,
    [EnumMember(Value = "gt")]
    GreaterThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "lt")]
    LessThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "in")]
    In,
    [EnumMember(Value = "like")]
    Like
}
public class GridFilter
{
    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void enumTest()
{
    GridFilter gf = new GridFilter()
    {
        Operator = FilterOperator.GreaterThan
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gf);

    // json yields {"operator":"gt"}

    var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GridFilter>(json);
    // ret.Operator yields FilterOperator.GreaterThan
}
```

Comment: Good thought but it didn't make a difference. It seems like the StringEnumConverter is being ignored since it works with or without it present

Comment: @Supergibbs that's my guess as well. I don't know if you saw my edit at the bottom there, but the source code is pretty clear to say it should be working. What if you manually add ([How to tell Json.Net globally to apply the StringEnumConverter to all enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427909/how-to-tell-json-net-globally-to-apply-the-stringenumconverter-to-all-enums)) the converter, rather than depending on that attribute? I know, not ideal, but if it's easy, let's see if that works, then we can at least know that.

Comment: Tried the global option, no luck

Comment: @Supergibbs I'm not sure if that surprises me or not, but that's good to know, either way. Hmm. I just edited my post, but basically I tried it and it worked for me. So there must be something else going on. Or rather, can you confirm that what I got, is your expected behavior? I assume so, but just to double-check, that's what *should* be happening, right?

Comment: Well I am actually having an issue with deserialization. I did the same thing as you though and it seems to work in a test. Maybe something with my project setup, it's gotten pretty big and complex. I'll try making a new bare bones one to test. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Supergibbs No problem, this is definitely a weird one. And yeah, I just added on deserialization in my test (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GridFilter>(json)`) and it works, so there must be something else at play. My guess would be something in the configuration of Web Api, granted I'm not sure what.