# C# - Deserialize JSON string to Enum[] using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have this JSON string

```
[ \"postal_code\" ]
```

My enum definition:

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "postal_code")]
    PostalCode,
}
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyEnum[]));
MyEnum[] myEnum = (MyEnum[]) dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(outputStream);
outputStream.Close();
//return myEnum ;
```

I get an error upon reaching the ReadObject line

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format: nDigits == 0.
```

How can I properly deserialize the JSON string to MyEnum?

I also want to avoid using JSON.Net. I'd want to go with DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: what do you have in `knownTypes` ?

Comment: ah, sorry, I set that to null, I've updated my post

Comment: I was thinking of giving a TypeConverter or some sort, but I'm not sure how to implement that correctly. I tried that, but somehow the TypeConverter is not getting called.

Comment: I decided to parse the string first and go with Enum.Parse http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx

Answer (score -1):

as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).

> Enumeration member values are treated as numbers in JSON, which is different from how they are treated in data contracts, where they are included as member names

Also

> All enum members are serializable. The EnumMemberAttribute and the
>   NonSerializedAttribute attributes are ignored if used.

So, try to use another deserializer for this purpose. Maybe [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) 
 or extend the JsonSerializer as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794838/datacontractjsonserializer-and-enums/794962#794962).

Comment: Why in the world would Microsoft handle enumeration values differently in JSON than in XML. It's still a data control regardless of the format. This is a travesty. I don't want to use third party JSON serialization, but Microsoft leaves no choice.