# WCF - Common library enum issue - C#

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, common-library

I've got a common library that contains enums that are shared between a WCF Service and a client by means of the DLL.  Yes, I know the better way of doing this is to create a service out of my common lib - that's for later.

I've made a change to my common lib, adding another field to the enum.  After compiling, I've updated the DLL's in both the WCF service and my web client.

Initially, I was getting the error:

> Ensure that the necessary enum values
>   are present and are marked with
>   EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the
>   type has DataContractAttribute
>   attribute.

This was quickly corrected by removing the check from the service reference configuration on the client, "Reuse types in referenced assemblies".

Now, however I am getting an error referring to the new enum value I added:

> Invalid enum value
>   'TestDataReceived_OK_NoDataWritten'
>   cannot be deserialized into type...

So this leads me to believe that there are two library versions out there, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I haven't setup any sort of [DataContract] areas in my service interface.  If I need to, some code sample would be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you regenerated your client-side service reference?

Comment: It's recommended to avoid enums in webservices because they create backwards compatible problems. Your problem is a perfect example of it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/788281/52277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to see this, I did resolve this by configuring the config files correctly.