# Get the values and description from Enum using DataContracts

Tags: c#, enums

I have a Service Data Contract as

```
public enum AddressType
    {
        [Description("Billing Address")]
        Billing = 0
    }
```

and if i give the reference to the page then the description not appears.

```
[DataContract(Name = "AddressType", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyEnums.Enums")]
public enum AddressType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Billing = 0
}
```

How to get the value and description in c#?

I will pass the AddressType and inside the AddressType all the values including the description needs to bind to the drop down list.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020597/how-to-expose-enum-attributes-wcf