# How to expose enum in WCF Service Help when response is generic XML

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service, xsd

I have an existing WCF Service with more than thirty functions each returning XML to the client app.  I enabled the help page by following these [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft.  This summarizes the methods of my service and lets me drill down to see the Request an Response formats, but does not include my enums. I'm opening up the service to a third-party vendor and I'd like to expand on the help file in a self-documenting way.

Unfortunately, I have most of my functions return a generic XMLElement like so:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate:="GetToken?u={sUser}&p={sPass}")>
<Description("Validates a user's credentials")>
Function GetToken(ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sPass As String) As XmlElement
```

The payload of several of these functions will include a handful of enumerated values, and table data. Because I don't have a strongly type Return, the Help page doesn't show any detail. 
I've checked other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020597/how-to-expose-enum-attributes-to-wcf-client), and I see differing advice on whether to expose the enums.  The part I'm missing is the actual details of *how* to do it.  I've tried using the following in both my IMyService.vb and MyService.svc.vb files, but nothing new shows up in my help page:

```
<DataContract(Name:="StatusCode")>
Enum StatusCode As Integer
    <EnumMember> Success = 0
    <EnumMember> UserNameMissing = -1
    PasswordMissing = -2
    PermissionError = -3
    AccountNotFound = -4
    BusinessRuleViolation = -5
    SystemDown = -99
    UnknownError = -100
End Enum
```

I tried some hokey workarounds like attempting to add multi-line comments to my  tags. I can't use "" & Environment.NewLine & "" concatenation or \n or 
 tags.  I started on trying to make a more strongly typed class that inherits from XMLElement, but I'd rather avoid the risk of breaking compatibility if there's some trick to the help file.

I see that I can add an XML Comment to the output file that gives some background info to developers, but they'd have to hit each of the methods to read it. (I've set it to only appear on the development server and not in production).

I suppose I could add another Method to the contract that just says ListMyEnums and returns a strongly typed set of the values, but that seems strange.  I would appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the XmlElement returned from your operation needs to at some point be deserialized on the client side to be of use? If so, then the consumer must already have some kind of equivalent object graph with which to work.

I think the simplest thing for you to do is to provide the consumer object graph via a consumer package released over something like NuGet or npm (or even just a shared assembly).

The consumer package would contain the actual graph you used to serialise the XML you're sending (enums and all), and could even encapsulate the means by which consumers call your service. That way you can control the object graph and deserialization of the XmlElement on the client.

Consumers would benefit because all they would need to do is consume your client package and then make the call, similar to how it works with WSDL and SOAP.

> The existing consumers are loosely coupled

I would actually expect a high degree of coupling between service and consumer. In fact, I would not use the term coupling in this instance, but *cohesion*. Highly cohesive software is good.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You are correct, the consumer will get a chunk of XML and deserialize it. The existing consumers are loosely coupled.  They treat the output like a string of text which happens to contain xml and then they parse it out.  We don't use any methods or properties of XMLElement after it is sent.  That's why I thought I might be able to re-factor to something like MyXMLElement and have it detailed right in the help doc.

Comment: @ja928 - It does beg the question as to why you just don't return the typed response and let WCF handle the encoding. Also, see update to my answer.