# Exposing Unused Enum from a WCF service

Tags: wcf, enums

I want to expose an enum to my client application without referencing it in my WCF Service. However the enum is not visible in the client application. Below is my code:

```
[DataContract]
public enum Columns
{
    [EnumMember]
    Column1= 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Column2= 1
}

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Columns))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Response GetObjects(Request request);
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do the "Request" and "Response" type look like??

Answer (score 3):

The `Columns` enumeration needs to be a property of either `Request` or `Response` classes as these are the only types included in the WSDL. The types that are exposed in the WSDL and thus *visible* to the client are only those that are used as input or output parameters (and all that are part of their class hierarchy) to the operation contract methods. So for example you could add the enum to the Request class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public Columns Columns { get; set; }

    // ... some other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ServiceKnownType attribute is designed to provide knowledge about subclasses not directly referenced. For instance, if you wanted a InheritedRequest class (which inherits from Request) to be able to be used in your "GetObjects" method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [DataContract] from on top of the **enum**.

you only use [DataContract] and [DataMember] on the **enum** if you want *some* of the elements in the **enum** to be available to clients of the service, but not all.  if you want all members of the **enum**, you leave it untagged.

Comment: no, don't - the [DataContract] is quite needed - but it's not complete - we also need to know how "Request" and "Response" look like - those ought to be using the "Columns" type in some ways....

Comment: @marc_s [DataContract] is not required for enums, and it doesn't effect if the whole enum will be generated or not. It's only important if you want to expose  some of enum values.

Answer (score 1):

The metadata of a service is meant to describe the types that are necessary in order to interact with the service - the request and response messages. You should make no attempt to include random types in the service metadata.

If you want to provide some random type to your clients, then the clients need to reference the type library that contains the types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to force your enum to appear in your WSDL when it isn't used by the service itself.

But if you maintain both the client and the server, you can use a shared library that contains types used by client and server.

In our projects, we don't use WSDL at all, we use the [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx) to create client proxies and reference the interface from a shared dll.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this elsewhere, but I'm going to add it here too...  Thought I would throw in what I found in relation to this.  Reading about the KnownType attribute, the deserializer has to have reason to think that the type you reference with KnownType might be passed.  If the deserializer knows all of the types in your data contracts or in your method parameters, it doesn't need your stinkin' "KnownTypes" to do its job, and so it ignores them.  If you have "object" defined as a type somewhere in your service.. uh-oh, poor ol' deserializer doesn't have a clue what type might be coming through there so it eats up all your known types and spits them out in the client proxy.

A hack?  Oh yeah.  If you are desperate, does it work?  Yep.

Answer (score 0):

For similar requirement I've created a dummy operation DummyForProxyGeneration in the service contract and added classes that I wanted to generate in proxy to the operation request or response. 
Btw, It is not recommended to expose enum in wcf response due to backward compatibility reasons.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/788281/52277