# Passing enums via WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to define an Enum in a project seprate to my WCF service project. I am creating an object which contains the enum and other data. when i pass the object via the WCF service to the client i get a not found.

Enum:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue,
    Green,
}
```

Object to be Passed:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Color ColorEnum { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Only if i give the object a default value of say ColourEnum = Color.Red does the service work. if it not set it breaks. i know this is a workaround but im looking for a solution that makes more sense instead of setting an arb value. and i just want to understand why it breaks

Thanks in advance

Comment: Man... Enums are never good to expose with services...

Comment: @AdilMughal Why? Enum are a good choice, and are definitely supported by the SOAP protocol.

Comment: I agree they are supported but based on some experiences...
Checkout stackoverflow post with some good discussion on Enum usage
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326339/do-you-use-enum-types-in-your-wcf-web-services

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have an enum in my WCF project like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CarBookReq
{
    [DataMember]
    public string RefNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RateType MyProperty { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public enum RateType
{
    [EnumMember]
    silver,
    [EnumMember]
    gold,
    [EnumMember]
    platinum,
    [EnumMember]
    young,
    [EnumMember]
    youngplus
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the [`EnumMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.aspx) attribute on your enum values.

Comment: yeah just did that now. still doesnt work - anything else missing. i put in [DataContract] above the enum aswell

Comment: @nivensookharan Do specify a default value for your enum. The serializer cannot specify a value for your ColorEnum property, as the default value is 0 and your enum starts from 1.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the default value for the property `ColorEnum` is not a valid value for your enum: when your create a `MyObject`, the default value for the property is 0, and 0 does not correspond to any value of your enum.

You have multiple options to correct this behavior.

- You can have `Red = 0` instead of `Red = 1` (or even omit it, it would have the same effect) in your enum declaration. That way, the default value would be Red instead of a nonsensical value.
- You can add a default value Default = 0 to your enum that you know will have the meaning of "the color has not be defined".
- You can have your propery be a nullable `Color?`, so null would become both a legal value and the default for the property
- You can have the constructor of `MyObject` assign a default color to the ColorEnum property.

  public MyObject()
  {
      this.ColorEnum = Color.Red;
  }

But whatever you do, the defaul value for an enumeration type will always be 0. if 0 does not correspond to a legal enum member, it's bound to be a problem.

Comment: So you saying if i add a enum `Default = 0,` is there no way for me over-ride the default of 0 other than giving the property some arb value which doesnt really make sense?

Comment: @nivensookharan : I have edited my answer with some options you have to solve your problem.