# Getting "Request Error" after hosting WCF on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-rest

Before hosting `WCF Restful` Services on IIS. I was getting response from server in my android application but now I have hosted my services on IIS but getting an error message of **REQUEST ERROR**. I don't know what's went wrong. can someone please sort out my problem. Thanks in Advance

**Before Hosting on IIS**

[image]

the above picture is before hosting the service on IIS. and the yellow highlighted text is `param` and the JSON is the response which is corresponding to that `param`.

**After Hosting on IIS**

[image]

I don't know why I'm getting this error. what went wrong and how to fix that. now im trying to retrieving data correspond to that `param` but getting an error message.

**"SERVER LOG  after `includeexceptiondetailInfaults` attribute value to true"**

I'ms sure that database is causing the error and you can view the picture of `server log` below

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the server logs like the error message suggested?

Comment: Where can I find this log ?

Comment: When you host Service on IIS, are you sure that you are hosting it correctly? Can you browse the service on IIS?

Comment: exacly can you browse: http://localhost/MyService/Quiz/QuizServ.svc? Have a look in the windows event viwer (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Note:  In the future, please post the **text** of the error message and stack trace, not a screenshot, as screenshots can be incredibly hard to read.  In any event, the issue is with the account your service is running under - it doesn't have rights to login to the database.  Either assign rights to that account, or better yet use a dedicated account to login and either run the app pool under it (with integrated security=true) or use the account name and password in the connection string.

Comment: @Tim found the solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database was causing an error. I have found the solution. what we need to do? We need to add a login to `SQL Server` for `IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0` and grant permissions to the database.

In SQL Server Management, under the server, expand Security, then right click the Logins and select "New Login...".

In the New Login dialog, enter the app pool as the login name and click "OK"

[image]
now right click the login, select properties and then click on the User Mapping Option. Click the appropriate **DATABASE** and check the properties roles. And we are done :).

hope you good luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions would be,

(i)Just ensure all your property are public.

(ii)To So see more details about the issue, you need to includeexceptiondetailInfaults attribute to true in servicedebug tag.

```
<servicebehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
          <servicedebug includeexceptiondetailinfaults="true" />
        </behavior>
</servicebehaviors>
```

(iii)Remove the Enum types (or use their suggested work-around and use a wrapper around the enum properties) and this should go away.

(iv)Copy the connection strings from the class library app.config to the web project web.config If you are using a class library and a web project,

Comment: Why to remove Enum types?

Comment: It's recommended to avoid enums in webservices because they create   compatible problems.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326339/do-you-use-enum-types-in-your-wcf-web-services/788281#788281

Comment: Well then, he haven't pasted code, but still the problem he is posing is not related to enum, moreover, REST services return response in JSON/XML. So, no worried of enum.

Comment: thanks for your response.
well I have searched alot but didn't find any solution. I think there is something wrong with my Database connection. I commented database connection and created an object with predefined values and it's work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

After hosting on  iis
Request  error occurred in  iis 
The  server  encountered  on  request  error  see  server logs for more details 
Solution 
 In  your  sql  server  change  window  authentic to  sql authentic  with  username and password
and  change  on  connection  string 
After  changing these step  and  refresh  the  iis  and 
Your  problem  is  solved