# Enum not getting serialized in WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm having a problem with an enum getting serialized in my WCF application.

I have a class `Account` which inherits from an interface `IAccount` defined as follows:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public interface IAccount
   {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
      public Country Country { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The `Account` class which inherits from `IAccount` is defined as:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   [DataContract]
   public Account : IAccount
   {
    [DataMember]          
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public Country Country { get; set; }
   }
}
```

}

The Country `Enum` is as follows:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public enum Country
  {
    America = 1,
    England = 2,
    France = 3
  }
```

}

Creating an `Account` object on the client side and calling the method AddAccount decorated with the `OperationContract` serializes the Account object as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddAccount xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <account>
                <FirstName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace">MyFirstName</FirstName>
                <LastName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace">MyLastName</LastName>
                <EmailAddress xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace">MyEmail@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
            </account>
        </AddAccount>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You will notice that the `Country` enum is not getting serialized.

I've tried everything from decorating the enum with DataContract and EnumMember and even explicitly setting the namespace in the attribute values for the DataContracts to even setting Values for the EnumMember attributes but nothing seems to work.

I don't know whether i'm going nuts and missing out something really obvious or is there something else that I would need to do that's not part of the code above.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the proxy class that was generated on the client side after adding the WCF application as a web reference I noticed that the enum is not decorated with `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]` like the other properties.

Comment: Don't use Enum types in your WCF Service.

Answer (score 8):

You need to decorate your enum with some contract information like:

```
  [DataContract]
  public enum Country
  {
    [EnumMember]
    America = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    England = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    France = 3
  }
```

Then on your service contract add:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Country))]
public interface IMyService {
// etc..
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( Please see my update above about the XML attribute. Maybe there's something else I would need to do in the config?

Comment: Not getting an error. The enum is not getting serialized and is therefore being set to its default value which is 0 on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The attributes have not helped me either.

First, for the enums, if somehow you are not setting its' values, the default value will be 0. And if you did not define a member with 0 value, the WCF will not serialize your enum.

So I would suggest putting a member in your enum with the value 0.

```
[DataContract]
public enum Country
{
   [EnumMember]
   None = 0,
   [EnumMember]
   America = 1,
   [EnumMember]
   England = 2,
   [EnumMember]
   France = 3
}
```

Comment: I would have never figured it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Enum should be decorated with `DataContract` and `EnumMember` attributes. Also you can add a `ServiceKnownType` attribute referencing your enum to the the service contract.

```
[DataContract]
public enum Country
{
   [EnumMember]
   America = 1,
   [EnumMember]
   England = 2,
   [EnumMember]
   France = 3
}
```

But in general I would recommend to avoid using enums in services as it leads to potential backwards compatibility issues. Here is a question and a good answer explaining this [Do you use enum types in your WCF web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326339/do-you-use-enum-types-in-your-wcf-web-services/788281#788281).