# WCF service creating separate proxy class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service method that sends back a `MembershipCreateStatus` (`System.Web.Security`) to the calling method. When I look at the service definition it has recreated the enum as a type of `MyProject.MyWebService.MembershipCreateStatus` so it is essentially a completely different object.

Is there a way in which I can tell the service definition to use the `System.Web.Security` class instead, even though it is this within the WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

You you can. You need to use the `KnownTypeAttribute` class to decorate the DataContract in your WCF Service to specify that the enum is of type `System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus` I'm not aware of the details of your environment but in general unless you control both the WCF service and the consuming clients, I would carefully research the support requirements and the possibility of a future change to the enum causing backwards compatibility issues with clients that are consuming this enum. Also to consider is a scenario where a non .NET client could consume your WCF service. In that case you need to consider if using the `System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus` enum is a good idea versus implementing your own statuses for Member creation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326339/do-you-use-enum-types-in-your-wcf-web-services) is another question on StackOverflow with a good discussion on this topic.

For example see the following code below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMembershipService
{
    [OperationContract]
    CreateMemberResponse CreateMember(ApplicationUser userToCreate);
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus))]
public class CreateMemberResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public MembershipCreateStatus Status { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public bool ReturnSuccess { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        ReturnSuccess = true;
    }
}
```

You can write a test against this service as follows and this test will succeed.

```
[TestClass]
public class MembershipStatusInvocationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateMemberShouldReturnMembershipCreateStatusEnum()
    {
        var client = new MembershipServiceClient();
        var response = client.CreateMember(new ApplicationUser {ReturnSuccess = true});

       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response.Status, typeof(System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus));
    }
}
```

For more information on the `KnownTypeAttribute` class see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)