# How do send a Collection of Enums to a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, collections, enums

I am having trouble sending a collection of Enums to a WCF service method. I used this post as a guide: [Sharing Enum with WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187505/sharing-enum-with-wcf-service)

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<MyEnum>))]
public interface IMyService{    
  [OperationContract]    
  MyEnum ServiceMethod1( );

  [OperationContract]    
  IList<MyEnum> ServiceMethod2( );

  [OperationContract]    
  IList<MyEnum> ServiceMethod3( MyEnum e );

  [OperationContract]    
  IList<MyEnum> ServiceMethod4( IList<MyEnum> e );
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnum{ 
  [EnumMember] red, 
  [EnumMember] green, 
  [EnumMember] blue 
};
```

ServiceMethod1, ServiceMethod2, and ServiceMethod3 work correctly. I get the following error when attempting to send a list of Enums to ServiceMethod4.

```
Operation 'ServiceMethod4' in contract 'IMyService' has a query variable named 'e' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[MyEnum]', but type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[MyEnum]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.
```

Do I need to create a custom QueryStringConverter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What does your configuration file look like?  It sounds like you might be using a `webHttpBinding` element which would not support `IList<MyEnum>` as that would be impossible to represent on a URL.

You should look into using a `basicHttpBinding` as this uses SOAP.  Using SOAP will allow you to serialize `IList<MyEnum>` and send it to your `OperationContract`.

Comment: I am using a `webHttpBinding` element and calling my service with a simple Get request passing the params on the query string.

    http://server/MyService.svc/ServiceMethod4?e=0&e=1&e=2

Why doesn't `webHttpBinding` serialize a list of enums? `webHttpBinding` will serialize a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to type that parameter as an array of MyEnum instead?  Then inside your implementation just use var eList = new List(e);  Alternatively, you could try using a KnownType helper class, as outlined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx

Comment: I previously tried changing the type of the parameter to an array of MyEnums but the parameter still doesn't serialize. 

I am also using the ServiceKnownType attribute as shown in the example above but it doesn't help the situation either.