# Got RuntimeException when call web service via ksoap2-android with pass enum as parameter

Tags: android, enums, ksoap2, runtimeexception

I want to add an enumeration as parameter of web service request.
I use ksoap2 on android but I got **java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: UNDEFINED**
when pass enumeration
I implement enumeration follow [How to pass an enum value to wcf webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827631/how-to-pass-an-enum-value-to-wcf-webservice) (Fildor answer)

```
interface BaseEnum extends Marshal
{
    public String getDesc(Enum en);
}
enum DrivingLicenseTypeEnum implements BaseEnum 
{
    UNDEFINED,
    NSURED_DRIVER_INJURED,
    INSURED_PASSENGER_INJURED,
    PARTY_DRIVER_INJURED,
    PARTY_PASSENGER_INJURED,
    THIRD_PARTY_INJURED,
    INSURED_VEHICLE_DAMAGE,
    PARTY_VEHICLE_DAMAGE,
    ASSET;

    public  String getDesc(Enum en) {
        String result="";
        //generate description
        return result;
    }

    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            PropertyInfo arg3) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.valueOf(arg0.nextText());
    }

    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope arg0) {
        arg0.addMapping("http://tempuri.org/", "DrivingLicenseTypeEnum", DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.class);
    }

    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer arg0, Object arg1)
            throws IOException {
        arg0.text(((DrivingLicenseTypeEnum)arg1).name());
    }
}
```

and I pass DrivingLicenseTypeEnum as parameter by

```
DrivingLicenseTypeEnum c = DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.UNDEFINED;
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("driverLicenseType");
pi.setValue(c);
pi.setType(DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.class);
request.addProperty(pi);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
c.register(envelope);
```

Could you please help me for resolve this problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I got an answer 
this problem is occur because I use enum that implements Marshal.
When I divide this enum to class and enum for example

```
enum DrivingLicenseTypeEnum 
{
    UNDEFINED,
    NSURED_DRIVER_INJURED,
    INSURED_PASSENGER_INJURED,
    PARTY_DRIVER_INJURED,
    PARTY_PASSENGER_INJURED,
    THIRD_PARTY_INJURED,
    INSURED_VEHICLE_DAMAGE,
    PARTY_VEHICLE_DAMAGE,
    ASSET
}

class DrivingLicenseTypeEnumClass implements Marshal
{
public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            PropertyInfo arg3) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.valueOf(arg0.nextText());
    }

    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope arg0) {
        arg0.addMapping("http://tempuri.org/", "DrivingLicenseTypeEnum", DrivingLicenseTypeEnum.class,new DrivingLicenseTypeEnumClass());
    }

    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer arg0, Object arg1)
            throws IOException {
        arg0.text(((DrivingLicenseTypeEnum)arg1).name());
    }

}
```

It work correctly.