# IEnumerable Collection Gets Cleared upon WCF Transfer

Tags: c#, wcf, collections, ienumerable

I have a class(say CustomClass) which has few properties of type `IEnumerable<Enum>`.

Pass the object of `CustomClass` over the WCF and return object of `Result` type(different type).

If I check `CustomClass` parameter in WCF after its gets everything done and about to send response back to the client, `CustomClass` parameter has that value, but by the time response reaches to the client, object of `CustomClass` clear all the contents of that List property.

I just want to know, why?

Structure of `Custom` Class is

```
 public class QuerySearchCriteria 
 {       
    [DataMember]
    public string DScope { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<SOURCE> Sources { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<ETYPE> ETypes { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Score> Score{ get; set; }       
}
```

Everything goes fine, but items in `Score` property are removed.

Comment: I guess WCF is \*puts on sunglasses\* keeping score... ***YYYYYEEEEAAAAHHHHHH***

Comment: Are there multiple instances of client/server?

Comment: What is the concrete type (GetType()) of Score(s) property ?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing based on the information you're provided but is `Score` a serializable class? In WCF, enumerations are automatically included since they're marked `Serializable` *unless* you've manually marked the Enum type class with `DataContract`. In that case, you need to mark each member of the Enum as `EnumMember`. This [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187505/sharing-enum-with-wcf-service) has a good explanation of how that works.

If I guessed wrong :) then you should enable [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and post the soap that is being created by the service to get more detail on what's going on. Also, posting the source for the `Score` class would be helpful.

Comment: I am testing it with WCF tracing as you suggest. In the meantime, Score is not a class, it is an enum.